# Custom web components vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there any way to pass parameters to the custom web component ? I need parameters for my component .
Class is extended html collection.

```
class CustomDropdown extends HTMLElement{

    constructor(){

        super();

        this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode : 'open' });

        this.setAttribute('expanded', there should be some parameter );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when you use your custom component you pass the parameters as attributes:

```
<custom-dropw-down expanded="true"></custom-drop-down>
```

Then, in the `connectedCallback` hook you can retrieve them:

```
connectedCallback() {
    const isExpanded = this.getAttribute('expanded');
}
```

If you want to set an attribute to the rendered DOM, you should also do that once the component has been rendered (for example, in the `connectedCallback` hook):

```
connectedCallback() {
    this.setAttribute('expanded', 'true');
}
```